# Designing the UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

So, this is my ViewController with UICollectionView:
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weKKJ.jpg)

This is the "Feed" controller, and the "Back" and "Upload" button are only temporary.

Any suggestion/tips on how I can make it look more professional, so it looks good?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish but I have found that simplicity is key. Maybe moving the timestamp to the very bottom right and making it grey so it doesn't draw the eye so much to it instead of the picture.

Comment: Yes, that was better actually. I want the cells and everything to look more "modern"(?) This now: http://s11.postimg.org/46lq79ek3/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_Shot_20_Nov_2015_20_57_11.png Any more tips?

Comment: without knowing what the app is for and who the audience is, its hard to help with the design. please also remember to upvote and mark the answer as correct.

Comment: This is a social media app. Whey post images, videos and plain text.